# Div with 2 columns. How to wrap the div contents? Extra space in left and right

Tags: html, css

movie class has two column class. 
But the two columns div do not fit in the movie div well. 
there is a space on left and right 
How to fit the two column div in the movie div well?

Image:

Answer (score 0):

Try adding padding instead of margin. This is only solution. Thanks

```
.movie{
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 33%;
    /*margin: 2px  10px; */
    padding: 2px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: hi, this is not what I want.  because i want gap between the divs. The divs have borders

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new `div` to be a container for your movie card because your styles override the `bootstrap` structure for the columns.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
  <div class="movie">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="title"><?= $movie["title"] ?></div>
      <div class="year">(<?= $movie["year"] ?>)</div>
      <div class="box-office">
        Box Office:
        <?= $movie["box-office"] ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img width = "80%" src= "posters/<?= $movie["poster"]?>"
      alt=“Poster” >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.movie {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: this is not collapsing the structure completely. 3 in a row is not fixed. I just need to keep 3 in a row with a margin. without margin it works

Comment: Okay, let me edit the answer to meet the **bootstrap** structure.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
         <style>
    .movie{


    }
    .inner-col {
       border: 1px solid lightgray;
        border-radius: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
        /*margin: 2px  10px; */
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .column {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;        
    }
</style>

<body>

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach ($movies as $movie) { ?>
                <div class="movie col-12 col-md-6  col-lg-4 "> 
                <div class="inner-col">
                        <div class="column">
                            <div class = "title"><?= $movie["title"] ?></div>
                            <div class = "year">(<?= $movie["year"] ?>)</div>
                            <div class = "box-office">Box Office: <?= $movie["box-office"] ?></div> 
                        </div>
                        <div class = "column">
                            <img width = "80%" src= "posters/<?= $movie["poster"]?>" alt=“Poster” >
                        </div> 
                </div>                  
                </div>



            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div></body>
```

Comment: This is what i get when i run your code https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hZ5nFtk5NcQsItvPaHYPMsqa1vII_zArsfZZKNtsbJ4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: remove   width: 33%; line from css